# How to display data from document to XPage?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am new to Lotus notes. Till now I am able to add data from XPage to the document and display it into a view. Now I want to display data into the fields on a XPage. Please suggest me how to do that And any good tutorial that suggest step by step development of an application on Notes.

Comment: As Brian M Moore pointed out, TLCC has some free courses. As you can see from [TLCC's developer courses page](http://tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/DeveloperView.xsp) that the [Introduction to XPages Development (9) course](http://tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/coursedetails.xsp?ccode=XP9INTR) is free; that would be a great place to start.

Comment: Start with the official tutorial: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-intro-to-XPages.htm and check the cheatsheet: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/learning-xpages ... and dont be afraid to ask

Comment: [Notes in 9 051: XPages Introduction (Extended Edition)](http://www.notesin9.com/2010/09/26/notesin9-extended-edition-intro-to-xpages/) is David Leedy's most popular video (according to [his YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/daveleedy)).

Answer (score 5):

In your custom control, bind the control to a document, drag a field (like a text field or computed field), and one of the panes will let you bind it to a field on the document.

There is a lot to this, you can look at Declan Lynch's blog posts (a bit old, but a great start) http://www.qtzar.com/learning-xpages/

You may want to pay for a class, I've taken some from TLCC and they are great: https://www.tlcc.com/ (I am not associated with TLCC, just a happy customer).

I know links out are not the greatest here, but part of this question was to point to tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

There are many hours of free video tips and tutorials on XPages over at the NotesIn9 Screencast.  [notesin9.com](http://notesin9.com).  Since the blog makes it difficult to find older shows, which still have value I have them indexed at [XPages.TV](http://xpages.tv) as well.  There's also a site at [XPagesCheatSheet.com](http://xpagescheatsheet.com) with some intro cheatsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Mastering XPages book.